# AngularJS - How do I get the state name inside of state resolve function to load controller files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, oclazyload

I am making head ways into diving into my first complete AngularJS app using PHP and tailored toward an api-centric approach.

I have reached this point:

I want to be able to capture the state name inside $stateProvider below for purpose of passing to load function.   However I am unable to get $rootScope.statename to be anything but undefined.   I have removed this from my solution because I could not get it to help remove undefined from the load function alert statement.

How do I capture (`risk` or `actionitem`) as the desired state name to be able to pass to the `load` function?

**app.js -Removed code snippet**

```
app.run( ['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
                      function ($rootScope,   $state,   $stateParams) {
                           $rootScope.statename = $state.current; 
}]);
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('Action', ['datatables', 'datatables.scroller', 'ngResource']);          
angular.module('Risk',   ['datatables', 'datatables.scroller', 'ngResource']);          

var app = angular.module('Main', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'datatables', 'ngResource', 'Action', 'Risk']);

app.config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($ocLazyLoadProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    configRoutes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider);
}]);
```

**route-config.js**

```
function load ($ocLazyLoad, $q, $rootScope){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    try{
        $ocLazyLoad.load($rootScope.statename).then(function(){
            deferred.resolve();
        });
    }
    catch (ex){
        deferred.reject(ex);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

```
function configRoutes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider)
{
    $urlRouterProvider
        .when('action', 'action')
        .when('issue',  'issue')
        .when('lesson', 'lesson')
        .when('opportunity', 'opporutnity')
        .when('risk', 'risk')
        .otherwise('main');


    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        modules: 
        [{
            name: 'action',
            files: ['app/tool/action/ActionController.js']
        },
        {
            name: 'risk',
            files: ['app/tool/risk/RiskController.js']
        }]
    });


    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: "/main",
            //templateUrl: '/app/tool/home/home.html',
        });

     $stateProvider
        .state('action', {
            name: 'action', <----------------------state name I want to capture for this url 
            url: "/actionitems",
            resolve: {
                loadDependencies: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$q', '$rootScope', load]
            },
            templateUrl: '/app/tool/action/ActionItems.html'
     });

      $stateProvider
        .state('risk', {
            name: 'risk',  <----------------------state name I want to capture for this url 
            url: "/risks",
            resolve: {
                loadDependencies: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$q', '$rootScope', load]
            },
            templateUrl: '/app/tool/risk/Risks.html'  
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the `allowed` method to the resolve section and cleaned up the code to get the desired outcome.  I declared a global state to capture the value in `$state$.name`

```
var state = '';

//route-config.js
function load($ocLazyLoad, $q)
{
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    try
    {
        $ocLazyLoad.load(state).then(function ()
        {
            deferred.resolve();
        });
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        deferred.reject(ex);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}


function configRoutes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider)
{

    var res = 
    {
        loadDependencies: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$q', load],
        allowed: function ($state$)
        {
            state = $state$.name;
        }
    };


    $urlRouterProvider
        .when('action', 'action')
        .when('issue', 'issue')
        .when('lesson', 'lesson')
        .when('opportunity', 'opporutnity')
        .when('risk', 'risk')
        .otherwise('main');


    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config(
    {
        modules: [
        {
            name: 'action',
            files: ['app/tool/action/ActionController.js']
        },
        {
            name: 'risk',
            files: ['app/tool/risk/RiskController.js']
        }]
    });


    $stateProvider
       .state('action',
        {
            url: "/actionitems",
            resolve: res,
            templateUrl: '/app/tool/action/ActionItems.html'
        });

    $stateProvider
        .state('risk',
        {
            url: "/risks",
            resolve: res,
            templateUrl: '/app/tool/risk/Risks.html'
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$state.current` has all the information about the current state, including the name. So `$state.current.name` will get you the information you need.

Comment: $rootScope.statename remains an empty string in the load method after I make the modifications to use $state.current.name in app.run

Answer (score 1):

Just keep the code simple:

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('action', {
        name: 'action', //<--state name I want to capture for this url 
        url: "/actionitems",
        resolve: {
            loadDependencies: function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load("action");
            }
        },
        templateUrl: '/app/tool/action/ActionItems.html'
 });
```

Comment: I added `allowed: function ($state$){state = $state$.name;} ` to set the global state var.  Then I use load state var in the load method.

Comment: I will try to simplify the code but I do appreciate the answer!