# AngularJS/Dependency Injection - How do I pass in a simple string literal in the dependency provider array for consumption as a value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, lazy-loading

I want to generalize my state code below to pass in a string to serve as an argument into load and that argument will be called module which is then parsed in load call for lazy loading.   Simply adding a string will error because Angular thinks it is a provider and triggers an unknown provider exception.

How can I achieve this objective?

```
function load ($ocLazyLoad, $q, $stateParams, module){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    try{
        $ocLazyLoad.load(module).then(function(){
            deferred.resolve();
        });
    }
    catch (ex){
        deferred.reject(ex);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}


 $stateProvider
    .state('action', {
        name: 'action',
        url: "/actionitems",
        resolve: {
               loadDependencies: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$q', '$stateParams', load]
        },
        templateUrl: '/app/tool/action/ActionItems.html'
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [`constant` provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#constant-recipe).  You can do something like this:

```
angular.module('my-module').constant('myConstant', 'my-value');
```

And then in your state provider:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('action', {
        name: 'action',
        url: "/actionitems",
        resolve: {
               loadDependencies: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$q', '$stateParams', 'myConstant', load]
        },
        templateUrl: '/app/tool/action/ActionItems.html'
  });

function load ($ocLazyLoad, $q, $stateParams, myConstant, module){
  // myConstant has the value 'my-value'
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank You,  seems my approach is complicating the issue.  I have referenced the question from a different angle here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55564581/angularjs-how-do-i-get-the-state-name-inside-of-state-resolve-function-to-load/55564770#55564770  to attempt to keep my code DRY but I still have left to find an answer